# Persists an object with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to store an object into a database using Hibernate but I get an Exception and I am completely lost about the reason.

I have developed two ways: First of all, using the save/persist/merge methods as follows:

```
sessionCARTIF.beginTransaction();
sessionCARTIF.save((Schedulers)object);
sessionCARTIF.getTransaction().commit();
```

In this case, the exception I obtain is thrown when committing results. It says `the transaction was nos successfully started`.

Secondly, I have try by common SQL query as follows:

```
String sSQL = "INSERT INTO SCHEDULERS(SCHEDULER_ID, SCHEDULER_NAME, START_DATE,"
                + "FINISH_DATE, TIMER, EVENT_ID, BUILDING_ID, EVENT_PROPERTIES)"
                + " VALUES ("+object.getSchedulerId()+", '"+object.getSchedulerName()+"', "
                + "to_timestamp('"+object.getStartDate()+"','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), "
                + "to_timestamp('"+object.getFinishDate()+"','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), "
                + " '"+object.getTimer()+"', "+object.getEvents().getEventId()+", "
                + "'"+object.getBuildingId()+"', '"+object.getEventProps()+"');";
sessionCARTIF.createSQLQuery(sSQL).executeUpdate();
```

In this second case, the exception says `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException`. However, the query has been tested with the database graphical interface and it works.

Any idea??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you opened the session before the beginTransaction method? i.e sessionCARTIF.openSession();

Comment: your sql query seems like not correctly formed.just try to use in `SYSO`

Comment: Are you using spring?

Comment: are you really bound to use SQL only?

Comment: I think your transaction is opened. for that if(sessionCARTIF.getTransaction().isActive()) sessionCARTIF.getTransaction().begin(); .... ..... .....   sessionCARTIF.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. Firstly, of course, I have opened the session. Secondly, the query has been tested in the Oracle environment and it works, then, I think it is well-formed. Third comment, no I am not using Spring. Fourth, I am using both SQL, different methods of Hibernate and no one works. Finally, I am going to try your code about checking active transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why you could be getting the error about the transaction not being started successfully. The first and most common one is because you are trying to do more than one transaction with the same session (Hibernate sessions are usually transaction bound, when you commit the session is closed unless you change the `auto_close_session` option to `false`).

The usual pattern is to create a `SessionFactory` object that creates `Session`s as needed:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  static {
    try {
      // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
      sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);  
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {  
    return sessionFactory;  
  } 
}
```

Then use the factory to create a session for every transaction, like this:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
   tx = session.beginTransaction();
   // work with the db
   tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  if (tx != null) {
    tx.rollback();
  }
  // Handle the exception, print message, etc.
} finally {
   session.close();
}
```

Another reason to get this error is because you're having a non transactional datasource or connection definition, or you have auto-commit enabled at database level or transactions are disabled (some DBs need specific drivers or libraries to support transactions, especially distributed transactions).

The reason why the SQL string generates an error could be caused by the conversion to string of one or more of the parameters you're concatenating into your SQL string. When you concatenate, Java calls the `.toString()` methods of each of the classes and the output could not be what you're expecting (especially with dates and non-string values). To verify that this is the problem, print the `sSQL` string and check the SQL that is actually being generated and eventually post that.

Note that concatenating values into an SQL instruction is considered a bad practice and can lead to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! It is better to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)s and set parameters separately. This also has the side effect of handling type conversion for you, especially for dates, for example:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SCHEDULERS(SCHEDULER_ID, SCHEDULER_NAME, START_DATE,"
    + "FINISH_DATE, TIMER, EVENT_ID, BUILDING_ID, EVENT_PROPERTIES)"
    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

stmt.setString(1, object.getSchedulerId());
stmt.setString(2, object.getSchedulerName());
stmt.setDate(3, object.getStartDate());
stmt.setDate(4, object.getFinishDate());
stmt.setString(5, object.getTimer());
stmt.setString(6, object.getEvents().getEventId());
stmt.setString(7, object.getBuildingId());
stmt.setString(8, object.getEventProps());

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that in this case you don't have to take care of putting quotes around strings and don't need to handle date formats as well, and SQL injection is guaranteed to not be possible in this case.

- See more at: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#jive_content_id_What_about_the_SessionFactory

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. If I understood correctly, your suggestion is when using pure java.sql, right? Or is it an example from the Hibernate framework? Apart from that, the session is closed every time I commit a result, isn't it? Because my driver is a multi-thread and I must commit results each time, so, if I understood you well, I must open the session each time I have to interact with the Database.

Comment: I updated my answer with sample code on how to create a session factory and instantiate sessions from it

Comment: Also, for the query arguments my suggestion regards pure JDBC calls, however Hibernate supports a similar mechanism with named parameters: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html